# bootable media to take a raw partition image?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, disk-utility

I'm looking for a free/commercial application on a bootable media to quickly take raw partition images, preferably with network support for destination.

I normally use ddrescue, but initializing a bootable desktop linux solution & HDDs, and dealing with the CLI is a little impractical. Of course there are some more task-specific linux distributions (like 'ultimatebootcd'), which one can be the answer.

I have two products from Paragon and Acronis, but don't think any of their products support raw partition backups through the bootable media. What I'm looking for is just like their boot disks, but with raw image support.

So I prefer;

- raw partition backup
- fast boot
- GUI
- network destination support
- ntfs destination support

**Note:** By 'raw', I also mean the destination image file shouldn't have a product-specific format, so I will be able to analyze it as a raw disk image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghost supported this at one point.

Encase definitely supports it.

R-tools pro supported it as well.  free trial available: http://www.drive-image.com/Drive_Image_Download.shtml

I can do it in the linux command-line for free or using some maybe a bit complicated tool combinations.  It sounds like you are looking for free AND easy.  I don't know of a free and easy way to do it.

Comment: Haha yeah those two keywords generally don't go well together. Thanks for your response. It doesn't have to be free. I'm also a big fan of ddrescue because of the way it works and it was the only tool which was able to copy my dead drive with just 8 unreadable sectors. btw there were even ghost-like free bootable linux distros with GUI, just don't remember their names if they are still active.

Comment: Clonezilla is the most powerful ghost-like open distro I remembered.  I have been previously flamed for recommending it though as it can be a little complicated.

Comment: Thanks aking. Looks like they don't support the raw format for the destination, except Encase, haven't tried it though. Yes, Clonezilla was one of the releases I forgot. Looks like I'll go with it or another linux distribution.